# Azure OpenAi Limit data to your content button not working as expected

Tags: openai-api, azure-openai

Prior to a few weeks ago I was able to deploy front end instances of AOAi that look at both data in my Azure instance AND ChatGPT data by unchecking the "Limit data to your content button" checkbox in AOAi Studio. This seems to no longer be working. Unchecking the box (which recently moved and has additional settings) allows both data sets in AOAi Studio (as it should), but deploying a front end (using the deploy button) builds a front end that does NOT have access to ChatGPT data (only the local dataset).

Anyone else getting this? Any ideas?

Tried starting over completely with all new infrastructure and got same result.

Comment: Do you have any system message that tells to answer only based on the data content? It might be not in their policy. You should create a support ticket. - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request